# Light filter for an experiment

Tags: visible-light, experimental-physics, experimental-technology

I'm looking for a filter that lets through as many wavelengths as possible (from 200  to 5000 nm).

Is that even possible?

Comment: how is that different from no filter? a vacuum is pretty good at transmitting those wavelengths ;-)

Comment: I need something to close the tube in which the experiment will take place. And the filters that are going to close it must let as much light as possible.

Comment: I have not heard of anybody making filters that have such a large bandwidth.

Comment: They make them, but they don't call them filters; mainly because they don't filter! Those are called windows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is usually called a window, not a filter. You need to check different manufacturers to choose a material that fits your requirements, including not only light transmission but also the pressure differential, chemical inertness, temperature range, etc. Checking [ARS' website](http://www.arscryo.com/Products/WindowMaterials.html), calcium fluoride (CaF2) might be what you are looking for.

Comment: My first choice would be CVI Melles-Griot. They make high quality optical components.